# MySQL to MongoDB query translation

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I need to convert following mysql query to mongo.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
        SELECT cr.*, COUNT(cj.job_id) AS finished_chunks FROM `checks_reports_df8` cr 
        LEFT JOIN `checks_jobs_df8` cj ON cr.id = cj.report_id 
        WHERE cr.started IS NOT NULL AND cr.finished IS NULL AND cj.is_done = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't do JOINs. So you will have to query both collections and do the JOIN on the application layer. How to do this exactly depends on which programming language you use to develop your application. You don't say which one you use, so I will just give you an example in JavaScript. When you use a different language: The second snippet is just a simple FOR loop.

These are the MongoDB queries you would use. I don't have access to your data, so I can not guarantee correctness.

```
var reports = db.checks_reports_df8.find({
      "started": {$exists: 1 },
      "finished": {$exists: 0 } 
});
```

This query assumes that your null-values are represented by missing fields which is normal practice in MongoDB. When you have actual `null` values, use `"started": { $ne: null }` and `"finished": null`.

Then iterate over the array of documents you get. For each `RESULT` perform this query:

```
reports.forEach(function(report) {

    var job_count = db.checks_jobs_df8.aggregate([
        {$match: {
            "report_id": report.id,
            "is_done": 1
        }},
        {$group: {
            _id: "$job_id",
            "count": { $sum: 1 }
        }}
    ])

    // output the data from report and job_count here

 });
```

Comment: Thank you @Philipp. This is exactly what I needed. The language is Python by the way. But it's very easy to adapt your answer. Thanks!